# Angular JS on Refresh loosing CSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

So weird things are happening. I have an angular page with routing, repeat etc., and it works fine. But if I press F5 in it, it always looses the CSS. I'm refreshing a partial view which is tied to a `_Layout`. So whenever I browse thru my page and press F5 on any page which is a partial view ONLY the partial view is refreshed and I loose all my CSS and layout elements. Why is that?

I'm using MVC btw.

For routing I'm using:

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/Account/PersonalInformation', {
            templateUrl:
                function (params) {

                    return "/Account/PersonalInformation/"
                }
        })
```

**EDIT**

as per request, PersonalInformation.cshtml, nothing special:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PersonalInformationJSON", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editUserForm" }))
{

    <div class="account_container">
        <div class="user_data  background_black">
            <div class="panel panel-default width-470 no_border">
                <div class="panel-body head_title_background no_padding"><h4 class="white margin-left30 bold">PERSONAL_DATA<h4></div>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="label">
                        @Html.Label(FIRSTNAME)
                        @Html.Label(":")
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Edit.FirstName, new { @class = "textbox_disable", @readonly = "readonly" })
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="label">
                        @Html.Label("LASTNAME")
                        @Html.Label(":")
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Edit.LastName, new { @class = "textbox_disable", @readonly = "readonly" })
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="label">
                        @Html.Label(.("USERNAME"))
                        @Html.Label(":")
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Edit.UserName, new { @class = "textbox_disable", @readonly = "readonly" })
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="label">
                        @Html.Label("BIRTHDATE")
                        @Html.Label(":")
                    </div>
                  <label class="textbox_disable">@Model.Edit.BirthDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")</label>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="label">
                        @Html.Label("TYPE_OF_LICENSE")
                        @Html.Label(":")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Edit.WebTypeOfLicense, "", new { @class = "red" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Edit.SelectLicenseId, Model.Edit.WebTypeOfLicense, "Choose type of license", new { @class = "textbox",id="type_of_license" })

                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="label">
                        @Html.Label("LICENSE_NUMBER")
                        @Html.Label(":")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Edit.IdentificationNumber, "", new { @class = "red" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Edit.IdentificationNumber, new { @class = "textbox", id="licence_number" })
                </li>

            </ul>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PersonalInformation(ManageMessageId? message, IndexPageModel model)
      {
          model.Edit = new EditModel();


          model.Edit.Country = new SelectList(CommonDbService.GetAllCountry(), "Id", "Name");
          model.Edit.WebTypeOfLicense = new SelectList(CommonDbService.GetAllLicense(), "Id", "Name");

          WebUser user = WebUser.FindByUsername(User.Identity.Name);

          ViewBag.StatusMessage =
              message == ManageMessageId.ChangeDataSuccess
                  ? "Your data has been changed."
                  : "";


          UserDebitInformation userDebitInformation = UserDebitInformation.FindDebitInfoByUserId(user.Id);


          model.Edit.UserName = user.UserName;
          model.Edit.FirstName = user.FirstName;
          model.Edit.LastName = user.LastName;
          model.Edit.BirthDate = user.BirthDate;
          model.Edit.SelectLicenseId = user.TypeOfLicence.Id;
          model.Edit.IdentificationNumber = user.IdentificationNumber;



          return View(model);
      }
```

Comment: Can you show us the line you use to import your CSS :D

Comment: `@Scripts.Render("~/My_Scripts")
        <script src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/angular-route.js"></script>`

Currently it looks like this in my _Layout

Comment: Inspect the html that is loaded. Are you loading only the partial view, or is the request made so the layout page is loaded as well? If you for instance remove the #-character from the url, things might get weird

Comment: @Patrick Nah # is not the problem tried it..

Comment: What is the url when you refresh the page? What does your PersonalInformation view look like?

Comment: @Patrick the URL stays the same but the content of the page is blank CSS just textboxes and labels, i looked at the inspector and it shows just /Scripts and <body>.. so only the PARTIAL view not the _Layout/PartialView if you get what im saying

Comment: So clearly your layout page is not loaded, which would suggest your url or your setup is not in match so to speak. Can you edit the question and include only the top of the personalinformation cshtml file, as well as the account controller code that serves the view for personal information? Can you also try to change the name of the route url, or the template name, so they are not the same, and see if that solves it temporarly?

Comment: @Patrick after editing the URLs it won't open them again :/

Comment: Hm, you're right, there's nothing that would impose on the layout. In what page do you have your ng-view, is that in your Index.cshtml page? Have you changed anything in your ViewStart page? Can you try to add @{ Layout = null } in the top of your personalinformation page, that will instruct MVC to not load the _Layout page when the personalinformation page is requested, since that should already be loaded by the page including ng-view, right

Comment: @Patrick there is _Layout= null forgot to include. sorry I even tried to mask the url to /Account/PI and when i refresh i created a new ActionResult in the controller called PI to redirect back to PersonalInfo an still doesn't work dammit

Comment: ^^ Don't be sorry. The only thing I can think of is that you don't have the #-sign in your url, and therefore your partial PI-page is loaded instead of the page with your ng-view, which would explain the behavior.

Comment: do you mean localhost/#/Account/PersonalInfo?

Comment: @Orom: Yes. The #-sign in that url would suggest your Index page of your Home controller (or whatever is set up in your route config) is loaded (with an ng-view) that replaces the content of the ng-viewdiv with the content from Account/PersonalInformation. Given the facts, this should work :-(

Comment: @Patrick Thanks i will try to figure it out with #-sign somehow!

Comment: Also, your templateUrl can be written as templateUrl: '/Account/PersonalInformation', no need for the function, or the trailing /-sign

Comment: @AlCode Were you ever able to find a solution to this? We are having the same issue.

Comment: @PhillipCopley Hi, I can not remember sorry, this is an old project, however there is a solution I just can not remember how.